# How to verify the contract(Smart) on Etherscan.io with the terminal code?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts

Been several days trying to verify my erc-20 smart contract on etherscan via the terminal with the hardhat command and keeps rejecting my petition

Before trying to do it with the terminal, I went to etherscan.io to the verify and publish page submitted my contract.sol code and all the openzeppelin contracts code concatenated but it kept rejecting me , so I decided to do it via the terminal with this line of code

`npx hardhat verify --network mainnet 0x56D66465162000Fc6c1B1dbf92713F811c0A7... 100000000 50`

where my cap is 100000000
And reward is 50 in my contract.sol file specified

but I get this output in the terminal

```
Nothing to compile
Successfully submitted source code for contract
contracts/Token.sol:Token at 0x56D66465162000Fc6c1B1dbf92713F811c0A7...
for verification on the block explorer. Waiting for verification result...

Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: The Etherscan API responded with a failure status.
The verification may still succeed but should be checked manually.
Reason: Fail - Unable to verify. Please check if the correct constructor argument was entered.

For more info run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces
PS C:\Users\conoi\Desktop\ERC20\jesse-token> npx hardhat verify --network mainnet 0x56D66465162000Fc6c1B1dbf92713F811c0A7... 100000000 50
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!